# Need example of calling stored procedure sp_SSISCloneConfiguration from a c# program on SQL Server

Tags: c#

When I use this code below, I get a -1 returned from line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

It may have something to do with `InvalidCastException`.

When we run this stored procedure manually in SSMS, it produces a SQL script in its output which we then copy and paste in a new window and run that to get what we want.

Any ideas of why it's not working from C#?

I knew the connection to the server is good.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_SSISCloneConfiguration", sqlConnection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@project", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = projectName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@destinationProject", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = projectName;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: If you are expecting a return value, I dont think `ExecuteNotQuery()` is what you want. Try `ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a `try-catch` and see if an error returns.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0

Answer (score 1):

Because `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns ["The number of rows affected."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery)

If you're expecting data as a result, you probably meant to use `ExecuteReader()` which returns ["A SqlDataReader object"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader), or perhaps `ExecuteScalar()` which returns ["The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference if the result set is empty."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar)

For example:

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Note that the *type* of `result` is `object`.  So if *"it produces a sql script in its output"* then you would probably need to convert it to a string, for example:

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();
```

Note the `?` operator being used, because `ExecuteScalar()` could return `null`.